# variable in FOR /F

Tags: batch-file, dos

I am new to write batch file
I have a simple.txt and its content:

```
aaa 1
bbb 2
ccc 3
bbb 4
aaaa 5
aaccdd 7
```

and run the batch file:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims= " %%a in ('FindStr "aa" ^"simple.txt^"') DO (
    SET TEMP_VAR=%%a
    echo %TEMP_VAR%
)
```

The result is

```
7
7
7
```

But what I expect is

```
1
5
7
```

Why does this happen? What I am thinking it is C-like or Java-like for loop. Is it really different from them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic problem for a person learning batch :-)

The entire FOR loop, including the contents of the parentheses, is parsed prior to the loop executing. Normal `%TEMP_VAR%` expansion takes place as part of the parsing, so the value you see is the value that existed *before* the loop is executed.

The solution is simple: Add `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` at the top, and use `!TEMP_VAR!` instead.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims= " %%a in ('FindStr "aa" ^"simple.txt^"') DO (
    SET TEMP_VAR=%%a
    echo !TEMP_VAR!
)
```

The HELP documentation provides a description of the problem. Type `HELP SET` or `SET /?` from the command line. The description of normal vs. delayed expansion is about 2/3 down from the top.